# Binaries inside windows docker not displaying error messages

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-container

Usually when binaries under windows are not able to load dependencies (e.g. a missing dll) they show that via a pop-up message. When I run the same binary inside a windows server core docker container the same binary just stops and cannot display the pop-up due to the container being headless. Is there any way e.g a log file where I can see the error message and debug the problem?

The PowerShell get-eventlog does not show anything related to this either.

The reason why I suspect the crash reason to be "missing dll"-related is, that the %errorlevel% return code of the program is `-1073741515`. Some googling showed it indicated for this error code:

> The generic description is "The application failed to initialize properly". That most commonly means that one of the application's components or support files - typically a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) - is missing.